# Living under the same roof

Tags: expressions

Can we say that: " I am living under the same roof with my dog" ?

As far as I understand the expression refers to a relationship and its challenges like for example marriage but can we use the same expression for relationships between humans and animals as well ?

Comment: It's not typically applied that way, no. But hey! So long as the jurisdiction where you live provides freedom of speech, you can say *anything you want*! Revel in it.

Comment: Is that the house roof or the kennel roof?

Comment: What if your pets are really troublesome what should we say then ? I thought that it would be fine if I say I have some problems living with my four cats under the same roof ?

Comment: @DavidPugh hopefully is a house roof :)

Comment: Certainly nothing wrong with saying that.  Of course, if you tell your buddies that and they know you're married they will assume you're in the doghouse.

Comment: I would say "as" rather than "with", but I'm not sure that's universal.

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that the expression _living under the same roof_ cannot be taken **literally**, with no connotation with regard to relationships?

Comment: No I just don't know if I can use it other contexts rather than relationships.

Answer (score 4):

*Living under the same roof*, seems to be [acceptable](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22under%20the%20same%20roof%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=dog%20%22living%20under%20the%20same%20roof%22) for a husband, wife, three kids and a dog in *[A Parenting Guidebook](https://books.google.com/books?id=oMOuXGoP2SkC&pg=PA65&dq=dog%20%22living%20under%20the%20same%20roof%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=p6A_VYsqxbqCBMqQgPAI&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=dog%20%22living%20under%20the%20same%20roof%22&f=false)*:

> Many families no longer consist of the stereotypical husband, wife,
> three kids and a dog, **all living under the same roof**.
>
> **Emphasis** mine

Families in general fit the description in *[Good Dog, Bad Dog, New and Revised](https://books.google.com/books?id=fAUtf046gl8C&pg=PA25&dq=dog%20%22living%20under%20the%20same%20roof%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=p6A_VYsqxbqCBMqQgPAI&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=dog%20%22living%20under%20the%20same%20roof%22&f=false)*:

> You wouldn't do that to a baby and you shouldn't do it to a dog.
>
> Bonding must involve the entire family, and that includes anyone
> living under the same roof. Each person should be encouraged to develop his or her own separate relationshp with the dog. The more diverse the relationships the better.

In general, dog lovers seem just as attached to their canine children as their spouses and biological children, as suggested by the dialogue in the novel *[Dog Handling](https://books.google.com/books?id=YK3RlDfEtYYC&pg=PA317&dq=dog%20%22living%20under%20the%20same%20roof%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=p6A_VYsqxbqCBMqQgPAI&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=dog%20%22living%20under%20the%20same%20roof%22&f=false)*:

> "He's called Felix. And I figured that while you had this thing about
> dogs, about training them, well, while Felix was living under the same
> roof as us then you wouldn't have to hound me so much."

One should be aware that dogs do not particularly enjoy *living under the same roof* as cats, as *[The Dog Bible](https://books.google.com/books?id=USfJJOu3VAkC&pg=PT621&dq=dog%20%22living%20under%20the%20same%20roof%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=p6A_VYsqxbqCBMqQgPAI&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=dog%20%22living%20under%20the%20same%20roof%22&f=false)* suggests:

> Cats and dogs are not natural enemies, but they aren't natural
> friends, either. When living under the same roof, they are in
> competition for food and water, territory and the affection of the people. If the two animals live together over several years, they come to an understanding and learn to respect the different issues that are important to each of them.

Your relationship with your dog is different than your relationship with your spouse, which would also be different than your relationship with your son, which would also be different than your relationship with you daughter. If you are ashamed of your dog, you might not want to document *living under the same roof*, but if you love it, why not let the whole world know?

Comment: I hadn't realized that dogs were particularly religious.

Comment: Have you read The Shooter's Bible,@LittleEva?

Comment: Scot's answer is spot on.  I do want to stress for the OP that this idea would normally not be expressed as a single sentence.  "Living under the same roof" is normally an explanatory subordinate phrase for another idea:  "My dog and I are a family of two that share all the similarities of anyone living under the same roof."